# Identify the credit card banner when entering the number

Tags: javascript

I am developing a system, where the user will have to make the payment via credit card. When he starts typing the first numbers on the card, the flag will be automatically identified and selected. I don't know much about jQuery or JavaScript.

**JS**

```js
var cartoes = {
   visa: /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})/,
   mast: /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}/,
   diners: /^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}/,
   amex: /^3[47][0-9]{13}/,
   discover: /^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}/,
   hipercard: /^(606282\d{10}(\d{3})?)|(3841\d{15})/,
   elo: /^((((636368)|(438935)|(504175)|(451416)|(636297))\d{0,10})|((5067)|(4576)|(4011))\d{0,12})/
};
```

The problem is that when entering the flag it is not working, that is, he is not selecting the flag as I type the card number. I tried with the cards I have: MasterCard, Amex and Visa. I will put the complete code.

```js
var cartoes = {
  visa: /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})/,
  mast: /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}/,
  diners: /^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}/,
  amex: /^3[47][0-9]{13}/,
  discover: /^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}/,
  hipercard: /^(606282\d{10}(\d{3})?)|(3841\d{15})/,
  elo: /^((((636368)|(438935)|(504175)|(451416)|(636297))\d{0,10})|((5067)|(4576)|(4011))\d{0,12})/
};
document.getElementById('num').addEventListener('keyup', testarCC);
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.fsResDir input[type="radio"]');

function testarCC(e) {
  var nr = this.value;
  var tipo;
  for (var cartao in cartoes)
    if (nr.match(cartoes[cartao])) tipo = cartao;
  // alert(tipo);
  if (tipo) document.getElementById(tipo).click();
  else
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) inputs[i].checked = false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Testando a Braspag</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <fieldset class="fsResDir">
    <legend>Dados do Cartão&nbsp;</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="RadBand" id="visa" />
    <label for="visa">
            <img src="bandeiras/visa.png" style="width: 90px" />
        </label>
    <input type="radio" name="RadBand" id="mast" />
    <label for="mast">
            <img src="bandeiras/mastercard.png"  style="width: 90px"/>
        </label>
    <input type="radio" name="RadBand" id="amex" />
    <label for="amex">
            <img src="bandeiras/amex.png"  style="width: 90px"/>
        </label>
    <label for="val" class="lab90">Validade:</label>
    <input type="text" class="ent20Form" id="val" name="TxtValMes" class="form-control" />/
    <input type="text" class="ent40Form" name="TxtValAno" class="form-control" />
    <label for="num" class="lab90">Numero:</label>
    <input type=text class="ent120Form" id="num" name="TxtNumero" class="form-control" />
  </fieldset>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Protip: don't convince yourself you're good enough to write robust code for handling payment information, you're not, and the risk of getting it wrong isn't worth the financial ruin. Find a CC payment handler (braintree, stripe, paypal, whatever) and integrate their service, so you're not liable for millions of dollars when your code invariably either does something wrong, or someone finds an exploit in it.

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks! I'm actually integrating the system with Braspag. The form would be to send the information to Braspag to be able to process the payment. Sorry about my English. I'm from Brazil and I'm using the translator for my post.

Comment: If you're integrating third party payment processing, you should have _no_ control over that: it should look and feel exactly as the payment service looks and feels everywhere else, so that people can trust you didn't hack something together that pretends to be the payment handler. In this case: their content being different from your own brand and look&feel is exactly what you want: people should know they're using something they can trust, not your a homerolled, probably already hacked (if not intentionally vulnerable) naive system.